# How to Insert Data into table with select query in Databricks using spark temp table

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, create-table, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I would like to insert the results of a Spark table into a new SQL Synapse table using SQL within Azure Data Bricks.

I have tried the following explanation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource] but I'm having no luck.

The Synapse table must be created as a result of a **SELECT** statement. The source should be a Spark / Data Bricks temporary view or Parquet source.

e.g. **Temp Table**

```
    # Load Taxi Location Data from Azure Synapse Analytics
        
        jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://synapsesqldbexample.database.windows.net:number;
database=SynapseDW" #Replace "suffix" with your own  
        connectionProperties = {
          "user" : "usernmae1",
          "password" : "password2",
          "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        }
        
        pushdown_query = '(select * from NYC.TaxiLocationLookup) as t'
        dfLookupLocation = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
        
        dfLookupLocation.createOrReplaceTempView('NYCTaxiLocation')
        
        display(dfLookupLocation)
```

e.g. **Source Synapse DW**

*Server:* synapsesqldbexample.database.windows.net

*Database:*[SynapseDW]

*Schema:* [NYC]

*Table:* [TaxiLocationLookup]

**Sink / Destination Table (not yet in existence):**

*Server:* synapsesqldbexample.database.windows.net

*Database:*[SynapseDW]

*Schema:* [NYC]

*New Table:* [TEST_NYCTaxiData]

**SQL Statement I tried:**

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE if not exists TEST_NYCTaxiLocation 
select *
from NYCTaxiLocation
limit 100
```

Comment: BTW your `%sql` is simply going to create a table inside your datalake storage, not in Synapse. By Synapse do you mean the relational storage engine?

Comment: Here's an example of what you need to do. https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid , by way of explanation. "Luck" was used for want of a better phase, as a friendly idiom. As in https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/any-luck#:~:text=convention,%5Binformal%5D . Apologies if it made my question unclear. I share your view “IT” is logic and development can often be trial and error. No luck, but we hope it goes right when we hit run , thank you for your support.

Comment: In answer to your question: "...By Synapse do you mean the relational storage engine"? I would like the end result to be a table, within my Synapse database. As follows:

`Server: synapsesqldbexample.database.windows.net ;
Database:[SynapseDW] ;
Schema: [NYC] ;
Table: [TaxiLocationLookup]`

I will review your suggested solution and revert my feedback and outcome asap.

Comment: In short to get parquet into synapse using insert/select, you need to define an external table in Synapse, point it at the parquet and insert it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid , thank you for the suggestion. Do you have any resources which detail the step-by-step instructions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Rereading your question: Can you confirm that you can only push the data into Synapse from databricks? You can't pull it in from Synapse? Here is one guide to pulling it in from Synapse but I guess that is not your objective https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/load-data-overview#define-external-tables

Comment: To push data into Synapse from databricks, try this. This code doesn't explicitly mention synapse though..... I'll see if I can find something (I am just googling here) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/spark-connector#write-data-to-azure-sql-and-sql-server

Comment: If you get that to work, make sure you use bulk insert, otherwise it's really slow and it writes loads of audit data into logging if you have it enabled. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/spark-connector#write-data-using-bulk-insert

Comment: @JPVoogt answer below uses the approach described in the databricks documentation here, which is slightly different to the approaches I already mentioned. https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use the com.databricks.spark.sqldw driver, then you will need a Azure Storage Account and a Container already setup. Once this is in place is is actually very easy to achive this.

1. Configure your BLOB Credentials in Azure Databricks, I go with the in Notebook approach
2. Create your JDBC Connection String and BLOB
3. Read your SELECT Statement into and RDD/Dataframe
4. Push Dataframe down to Azure Synapse using the .write function

   ## CONFIGURE BLOB CREDENTIALS

   spark.conf.set(
   "fs.azure.account.key..blob.core.windows.net",
   "")

   ## CONFIGURE JDBC AND BLOB PATH

   jdbc = "jdbc:sqlserver://.database.windows.net:1433;database=;user=@;password=;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
   blob = "wasbs://@.blob.core.windows.net/"

   ## READ DATA FROM SYNAPSE INTO DATAFRAME

   df = spark.read 
   .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") 
   .option("url", jdbc) 
   .option("tempDir", blob) 
   .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") 
   .option("Query", "SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM <> ORDER BY NEWID()") 
   .load()

   ## WRITE DATA FROM DATAFRAME BACK TO AZURE SYNAPSE

   df.write 
   .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") 
   .option("url", jdbc) 
   .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") 
   .option("dbTable", "YOURTABLENAME") 
   .option("tempDir", blob) 
   .mode("overwrite") 
   .save()

Comment: Did a quick write up for you as well @ http://blog.voogie.online/code/2020/11/03/Read-and-Write-Data-From-Azure-Synapse-to-Azure-Databricks/

Comment: I will try your solution and revert with the result asap. In the meanwhile, thank you very much for your solution and friendly response. Before marking as the answer please allow me time to test and feedback. 

Answer (score 0):

another option besides @JPVoogt solution is to use CTAS in the Synapse pool after you've created your parquet files in the storage account. You could either do the copy command or external tables.

Some references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-cetas
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/quickstart-bulk-load-copy-tsql

Comment: also thank you for your support. I will also attempt your suggestion, using the links provided for reference. If I encounter any issues, I’ll PM you and update the post with the end result. Thank you in advance. P.s Before marking as the possible answer please allow me time to test and feedback.